# Как считывать данные с nfc?

Tags: android, nfc

Есть биометрический паспорт, которая поддерживает nfc.
В play market -е есть приложения которые считывают эти данные, и там выходит вся информация.
Я реализовал проект по этому примеру:
https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-nfc-reader-application-for-android-74cf24f38a6f

Он работает, но только дает такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А где брат другие данные не пойму.
Подскажите как правильно это реализовать.

Comment: Другие данные, это какие?

Comment: я считываю данные с биометрического паспорта. А в нем немало инфо-ии, Ф.И.О и т.д.....

Comment: Гляньте это, может поможет: https://github.com/tananaev/passport-reader

Comment: спасибо за ссылку